# Line Segment Question (limited info)

Tags: analysis

The problem:

I have a perfectly vertical line with 3 points (A,B,C).

Point A's y value (1st endpoint) = unknown
Point B's y value (a point in the line, not necessarily the exact midpoint) = 3.12
Point C's y value (2nd endpoint) = 2.71

I also know that:    By - ( (Ay-By) x 1.618 ) = 2.71  AND Ay < 4.38

I need to find the value of endpoint Ay.

Is this problem solvable?

Answer (score 0):

$B-1.618(A-B)=2.71\\B=3.12\\3.12-1.618(A-3.12)=2.71\\1.618A=3.12(2.618)-2.71\\A=\frac{3.12(2.618)-2.71}{1.618}\approx 3.3734$

Comment: Thank you.  But where did you get the 2.618 value?

Comment: I added 1 to 1.618 in the factors of 3.12